# UninitializedPropertyAccessException using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppDataModule {
     @Provides
     @Singleton
     fun provideAU(loginPreferences: LoginPreferences, @ApplicationContext context: Context): AccountUtil = AccountUtil (loginPreferences, context)
}

class SomeClass { 

    @Inject
    lateinit var accountUtil: AccountUtil

    constructor(context:Context){}

    constructor(context:Context, obj:SomeClass1){}

    init {
       accountUtil.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

I got

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property accountUtil has not been initialized

How can i resolve this one? is i need to use custom component in Hilt?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your application as a @HiltApplication

```
@HiltAndroidApp class Application: Application()
```

Then once you've created a module like so

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppDataModule {
     @Provides
     @Singleton
     fun provideAU(loginPreferences: LoginPreferences, @ApplicationContext context: Context): AccountUtil = AccountUtil (loginPreferences, context)
}
```

Make sure the class you're wanting to inject is injected in the constructor

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor(private var accountUtil: AccountUtil) { 
    init { accountUtil.isLoggedIn() }
}

class SomeClass @Inject constructor(){ 
    @Inject constructor(private var accountUtil: AccountUtil)
    @Inject constructor(private var util1: AccountUtil, private var util2: AccountUtil)
    init { accountUtil.isLoggedIn() }
}
```

Comment: If SomeClass have multiple constructor then how can i inject? @Brandon

Comment: @Arun I've updated the answer to show multiple constructors